# How to pass start variable to for loop, BASH

Tags: bash, variables, for-loop

Good day,

I was wondering how to properly pass a variable to a `for` loop. Doesn't matter the syntax, I just want to pass the variable and count by two.

The issue:

when I write down:

```
r=0 ; for i in {"$r"..10..2}; do echo "Welcome $i times" ;done
```

I get:

```
Welcome {0..10..2} times
```

and not:

```
Welcome 0 times
Welcome 2 times
Welcome 4 times
Welcome 6 times
Welcome 8 times
Welcome 10 times
```

Thanks in advance for any clue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arguments passed into for loop in bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764383/arguments-passed-into-for-loop-in-bash-script)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general format for a `for` loop that utilizes variables for loop boundaries is:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=2
b=10
increment=2

for ((i=$a; i<=$b; i+=$increment)); do
    ## <something with $i>
    echo "i: $i"
done
```

**output:**

```
$ bash forloop.sh
i: 2
i: 4
i: 6
i: 8
i: 10
```

Comment: Thank you, ... a last question, How can I count by two?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness,

In stead of

```
for i in {"$r"..10..2};
```

you can try

```
for i in $(eval echo {$r..10..2});
```

However, I highly discourage you to use this solution, but go for David's solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your complete answer, have a good day! : )

Comment: Nice Trick! If you want a leading zero, this method works well. `for n in {001..10}; do echo $n; done`

Answer (score 0):

You can not use variable in `{a....b}` syntax. But you can use `seq`.

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17787713/3576835)

Comment: mmm... yes, it is possible: http://s0.cyberciti.org/uploads/cms/2012/10/bash.for_.loop_.pdf That depends on bash version

Comment: See, I mean to say that you can not use variable inside braces. Even that document is not using it. For latest info about bash you should see this [gnu bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs)

Comment: @Alejandro `Brace expansion is performed before any other expansions, and any characters special to other expansions are preserved in the result. It is strictly textual.  Bash does not apply any syntactic interpretation to the context of the expansion or the text between the braces.` Also wouldn't really rely on your link as a guide, since there are some fairly bad examples with minimal explanation in there, e.g. `while true; do ...` is an infinitely more readable infinite loop than `for ((;;)); do ...`.